# SQL Error: Invalid table name

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create table (orders) with some foreign keys by using this query statement,

```
CREATE TABLE orders

)
order_id    VARCHAR2(20),
item_id     VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT item_id_not_null NOT NULL,
quantity_id VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT quantity_id_not_null NOT NULL,
customer_id VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT mobile_no_not_null NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT order_pk PRIMARY KEY(order_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_customer FOREIGN KEY (customer_Id) REFERENCES ORDER(customer_Id),
CONSTRAINT fk_item FOREIGN KEY (item_Id) REFERENCES ORDER(item_Id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_quantity FOREIGN KEY (quantity_Id) REFERENCES ORDER(quantity_Id)
 );
```

I get the following back,

> SQL Error: ORA-00903: invalid table name
>   00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"

Comment: i already used table name orders.

Comment: You need to use `(` right after the table name, not `)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the FK definitions. The table should be `ORDERS` and not `ORDER`, which is a reserved keyword.

Comment: i already used table name orders.

Comment: I am referring to the "CONSTRAINT fk_customer FOREIGN KEY (customer_Id) REFERENCES ORDER(customer_Id)...."

Comment: You are trying to reference table ORDER here, which unless you declare and use it under double quotes you can't use this keyword.